# Изменить адрес страницы

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Как изменить адрес страницы? Т.е. каким образом действуют системы ЧПУ и им подобные? Они ведь не используют GET запросов, с помощью которых бы формировалась страница? Или создают?

Например, у меня на Wordpress есть страница site.ru/privet как мне сделать так, чтобы она открывалась по адресу site.ru/poka ?

Comment: зачем плодить вопросы? =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если применительно для apache, то в файле .htaccess пишем примерно следующие:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^poka$ /privet [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

еще, можно просто положить в корень символическую ссылку под названием "poka", ссылающуюся на "privet", и включить:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
</IfModule>
```

а вообще, у модуля mod_rewrite много разных возможностей, погуглите.